# ng-repeat works with <p>, <ul><li>, etc, but fails on select using exact same source

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

Part of an app to populate a list of common phone and tablet models based on a mobile OS choice is shown here:

```
<div class="input-field col s3">
                <label class="active">Environment (OS)</label>
                <select ng-model="environment" ng-change="listBrowsers()">
                    <option value="" disabled>Select an OS</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="OS in OSes">{{OS}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

And a snippet of $scope.listBrowsers() for context (from the controller)....

```
$scope.listBrowsers = function() {
    $scope.browsers = MachineDataService.getBrowsers($scope.environment);
    $scope.browser1 = null;
    $scope.notMobile(); //calls another function to determine mobile-ness
    $scope.getMobileDevices($scope.environment);
    return $scope.browsers;
}
```

Next the 'getMobileDevices' scope function calls a similarly named service method:

```
this.getMobileDevices = function(envt) {
    var deviceList = [];
    for (i=0; i < _devices.length; i++) {
        if (_devices[i].versions.indexOf(envt) > -1) {
            deviceList.push(_devices[i].name);
        }
    }
    return deviceList;
```

}

But then the problem comes in the resulting changes to the view:

This works --

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
                <label class="active">Phone/Tablet Model:</label>
                <p ng-repeat="device in mobileDevices">{{device}}</p></div>
```

This doesn't:

```
<div class="input-field col s6><select ng-model="mobileDeviceType">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a device...</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="device in mobileDevices" value="{{device}}">{{device}}</option>
                </select></div>
```

In fact, even replacing the select with radio buttons worked -- from the same source!

N.B. I will admit I may be missing something -- Angular is still somewhat new to me.  Pardon the use of Materialize rather than Angular Material -- I'll probably rewrite later to use Angular Material, but didn't know of its existence at the start.

Edit -- to help illustrate the point, here's a screenshot of the result with the paragraph using the repeater, and with the select using ng-options instead.

[sample-with-ngoptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxB1u.png)
[sample-with-paragraph-ngrepeat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrux5.png)

Comment: Option element uses ng-options. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: I know that's the preferred way, but oddly enough that failed, too, and I've used it successfully elsewhere in the same app.  Here it would have been <select ng-options="device for device in mobileDevices">

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly it worked for me here ! I took the same snippet code you have provided and made this demo and it's working fine.Can you check if you are doing the same ?

Although you have a syntax error in your provided code `<div class="input-field col s6><select ng-model="mobileDeviceType">`

Change that  to `<div class="input-field col s6"><select ng-model="mobileDeviceType">` you missed a `"` at the end of class attribute

```js
var adminPage = angular.module("adminPage", []);
adminPage.controller('adminPage1', function($scope, $http, $window) {



  $scope.mobileDevices = ['Apple', 'HTC', 'Samnsung', 'One plus'];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="adminPage" ng-controller="adminPage1" class="input-field col s6">
  <select ng-model="mobileDeviceType">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a device...</option>
    <option ng-repeat="device in mobileDevices" value="{{device}}">{{device}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish it were that simple.... I think the missing " is actually a copy-paste error (my bad) - I'm looking back at the original Pen and the class attribute is closed there.

Comment: It wouldn't make a lot of sense for this to be the problem given the traces I've done (inserting alerts at various stages before the loop in the service method, after the loop, and then finally from the controller), but the service variable this comes from is an array of objects with one property being an array -- e.g. _devices = [{model: iPhone4s; versions: ["iOS5","iO6","iOS7","iOS8","iOS9"]}]